# Find a spd matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $\langle Cv_i,v_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be set of eigenvectors of matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Find a symmetric positive definte matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $\langle Cv_i,v_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is the standard Euclidean matrix norm.

I have no idea to find the matrix $C$. Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be the matrix associated (with respect to the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$) to the linear isomorphism given by $v_i\mapsto e_i$, $i=1,\dotsc,n$ (here, $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ denotes the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$). This is of course only possible if $v_1,\dotsc,v_n$ already form a basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then $C:= B^TB$ is symmetric and positive definite and it holds
$$
\langle Cv_i,v_j\rangle = \langle B^TBv_i,v_j\rangle = \langle Bv_i,Bv_j\rangle = \langle e_i,e_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $V$ be the matrix whose columns are the $v_i$ and rewrite the equation $\langle Cv_i,v_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$ as a matrix equation. You will need to assume that the $v_i$ are linearly independent.